GCP vTPM: DA lockout mode
After restarting the compute engine vm many times, I get this error:
"Failed to fetch and write OIDC token: failed to retrieve attestation service token: failed to attest: failed to quote: warning code 0x21 : authorizations for objects subject to DA protection are not allowed at this time because the TPM is in DA lockout mode"
How can I get around TPM issues? I want to be able to restart my vm as many times as I want.
